# Angular spy On not working for stubbing mock

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I have angular 4 application and i am writing test cases using jasmin + Karma

My first test case working properly as it creates component and service instance,

But second test cases is failing as it is not able to fetch mock data for 'getorders' method, when i log its value is undefined.

```
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [ OrderListComponent ],
          providers: [
            OrderFormFetchService,
          ],
          imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            BrowserAnimationsModule,
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            HttpClientModule,
            RouterModule.forRoot([]),
            NglModule.forRoot({svgPath: 'assets/icons'}),
          LayoutModule,
          NgbModule.forRoot()
        ],
        })
        .compileComponents();
      }));


 beforeEach(() => {
        orderFormFetchService = TestBed.get(OrderFormFetchService);
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OrderListComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        orderListStub = [{
          'id': '5c18e74dd5ab9332cc473c94',
          'createdAt': '2018-12-18T12:25:49.507Z',
          'updatedAt': '2018-12-18T12:25:49.507Z',
          'name': 'apple',
          'website': 'www.apple.com',
          'secsId': ''
        }];
        spyOn(orderFormFetchService, 'getorders').and.returnValue(Observable.of(orderListStub));
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });

      it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
        expect(fixture).toBeDefined();
        expect(orderFormFetchService).toBeDefined();
      });

     it('check order list ', () => {
      console.log(orderFormFetchService.getorders()); // -> undefined
      expect(component.orderList).toBeDefined();
      //  expect(component.orderList).toEqual(orderListStub);
      });
```

Code in OrderListComponent   is as follows,

```
export class OrderListComponent   extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {

  defaultQuery = {website: null, name: null};
  orderList: any;
  query = _.clone(this.defaultQuery);
  date: Date;

  constructor(private orderFormFetchService: OrderFormFetchService) { super(); }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.date = new Date();
    this.getOrderList();
  }

  getOrderList(): void {
    this.orderFormFetchService.getOrders()
      .subscribe((res: Response) => {
        if (_.isArray(res)) {
          this.orderList = _.orderBy(res, [order => order.name.toLowerCase()], ['asc']);
        } else {
          this.orderList = [res];
        }
      });
  }
  }
```

Please help

Comment: Can you show the code of the `OrderListComponent`? And I think this `orderFormFetchService = TestBed.get(orderFormFetchService);
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(orderListComponent);` should be `orderFormFetchService = TestBed.get(OrderFormFetchService);
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OrderListComponent);` (capital O's).

Comment: @FabianKüng, I have updated with component code

Comment: `spyOn(orderFormFetchService, 'getorders').and.returnValue(Observable.of(orderListStub));` make sure you name the correct function, should be `getOrders` and also I think the spy should return the same type as the original function, which would be of type `Response`I assume?

Additionally I would define the spy in the test itself like this: `const mySpy = spyOn(..)` and then you can check if your spy actually gets called like this `expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalled();`.

Comment: From service its returning Observable<any> but in component this method subscribe with Response return type

Comment: Maybe we are missing some crucial information but when I try to reproduce a it in a stackblitz it works fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/testing-jnllr6?file=app/order-list/order-list.component.spec.ts

Comment: this link is not working for me

Comment: @FabianKüng.. could you please give me unit testing example for component using order service to initialize orderlist in component  , test with single order and multiple orders array